# Accept a string and remove duplicate characters, using Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am newly learning Haskell and with the help of previously asked similar questions, I reached the following code, but I am getting an error -

```
Couldn't match type ' [ ] ' with ' IO '.
Expected type - IO Char
Actual type - [Char]
```

---

```
import Data.Set

removeDups :: Ord a => [a] -> Set a -> [a]
removeDups [] sofar = []
removeDups (x:rest) sofar
     | member x sofar = (removeDups rest sofar)
     | otherwise      = x:(removeDups rest (insert x sofar))
main = do
  name <- getLine
  removeDups name empty
```

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is that `removeDups` returns the type `[a]`, but when you have a function called inside a `do` block it must match the monadic type of that `do` block.  In this case, you're calling it inside `main`, which must have type `IO ()`, so the compiler expects `removeDups` to have a return type like `IO a`, but it actually the return type `Ord a => [a]`.  You could instead do something like

```
main = do
    name <- getLine
    let unique = removeDups name empty
    print unique
```

Since `print` has the return type `IO ()`.